# Try to make Haskell logger for learning but restrictions of Monad instances stand in my way

Tags: haskell

```
import Control.Monad

data Logger l a = Logger {runLogger :: (IO (),a,l)}

iologger :: (Show l)=> l->a->(a->b)->Logger l b
iologger l a f = Logger (print l,f a,l) 

instance (Show l)=>Monad (Logger l) where
  return a = iologger (show "") a id
  logger>>=f = let (_,va,vl) = runLogger logger
           in iologger vl va f
```

The above code does not compile. What I want to make is something like this(code below is F# computation expressions)

```
let loggedWorkflow = 
logger
    {
    let! x = 42
    let! y = 43
    let! z = x + y
    return z
    }
```

The above code logs the result because of this

```
type LoggingBuilder() =
    let log p = printfn "expression is %A" p

    member this.Bind(x, f) = 
        log x
        f x

    member this.Return(x) = 
        x
```

But this does not work in Haskell because `print` wants `Show` restriction. The `Writer` monad cannot do this also because is explicit. In every code you write you must put `tell`. Any ideas?

Comment: Very not clear what you're trying you do in Haskell there. For example, what is the purpose of `IO ()` in `Logger` and why are you discarding it in bind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RebindableSyntax` to redefine `(>>=)` in any way you want.

Note that this is does not satisfy the monad laws, unless you consider an equivalence relation on programs that is oblivious to differences in logging.

There is also some more noise with those `return` because is no `let!` syntax that desugars to `(>>=)`.

Also, why would you not call `log` just where it is necessary?

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}

import qualified Control.Monad as Monad
import Prelude (IO, Show(show), (++), putStrLn, ($), fromInteger, Int, (+))

class CMonad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=) :: Show a => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

log :: Show a => a -> IO ()
log x = putStrLn $ "Expression is: " ++ show x

instance CMonad IO where
  return = Monad.return
  m >>= k = m Monad.>>= \a -> log a Monad.>> k a

main :: IO Int
main = do
  x <- return (42 :: Int)
  y <- return (43 :: Int)
  z <- return (x + y)
  return z
```